# Yii2: Fill form automatically only when triggered

Tags: yii2

How to fill a form automatically, but only when it is requested by the user.
That is, the fields are not populated when the form is generated.

Por example:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'city')->textInput() ?>
```

When the form is accessed, the field is empty. And what I want is that there is a button, which when the user clicks, automatically the field is populated with the value of the "city" that is in the "User" table.

Form:

City : __________ | get my city |

After user clicked on button "get my city":

City : _London___ | get my city |

Comment: fill it via ajax call, like when you do autocomplete

Comment: @Ripper you can indicate something? I'm watching this right now https://youtu.be/hZ-6huMYxBc?list=PLRd0zhQj3CBmusDbBzFgg3H20VxLx2mkF

Comment: what is model name ? or input id ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At last no ajax needed

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <?= Html::activeLabel($model, 'city') ?>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-9">
        <?= $form->field($model, 'city')->textInput()->label(false) ?>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">
        <?= \yii\helpers\Html::button('get my city', ['id' => 'get-user-city-btn']) ?>
    </div>
</div>

<?php $this->registerJs("
    $('#get-user-city-btn').on('click', function(){
        $('#id-of-city-input-goes-here').val('"
            . Yii::$app->user->identity->city
        . "');
    });
", $this::POS_END, 'get-user-city-script'); ?>
```